# How to capture cell's output in Databricks notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, databricks, azure-databricks

I tried using: `%%capture my_cap`
but it gives an error:

```
TypeError: run_cell() missing 1 required positional argument: 'raw_cell'
```

So it's unusable :-(  Any other options out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first cell include this:

```
from IPython.utils.capture import CapturedIO   
capture = CapturedIO(sys.stdout, sys.stderr)
...
...
# at the end of desired output:
cmem = capture.stdout
```

In the 2nd cell you can access variable `cmem`:

```
print(cmem)
```

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: didn't work for me when installing a package