# Saving PySpark standard out and standard error logs to cloud object storage when running on databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I am running my PySpark data pipeline code on a standard databricks cluster. I need to save all
Python/PySpark standard output and standard error messages into a file in an Azure BLOB account.

When I run my Python code locally I can see all messages including errors in the terminal
and save them to a log file. How can something similar be accomplished with Databricks and Azure
BLOB for PySpark data pipeline code? Can this be done?

Big thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store error logs to azure storage account.

**Please follow below steps:**

1.Create a mount to azure blob Storage container, If you already have log file then store logs to mount location.

**Access key**

[image: Ref1]

```
dbutils.fs.mount(    
    source = "wasbs://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/<mount_name>",
    extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net":"< storage_account_access key>})
```

[image: Ref2]

**2.Filepath Creation**

As per your requirement you can change time zone and save your file.(Example: IST, UST…etc.)

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
curr_dt=datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')).strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")#create timezone
directory="/mnt/"
logfilename="<file_name>"+curr_dt+"log"
path=directory+logfilename
print(path)
```

[image: Ref3]
**3.File Handler**

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('demologger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
FileHandler=logging.FileHandler(path,mode='a')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s',datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
FileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(FileHandler)
logger.debug( 'debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical ('critical message')
```

**4.create partition**

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
partition=datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
print(partition)
```

[image: Ref4]

**5.Uploading Logs file Storage Account.**

```
 dbutils.fs.mv("file:"+path,"dbfs:/mnt/<filelocation>/log/"+partition+logfilename)
```

[image: Ref5]

**Output:**

[image: Ref6]

**Reference:**

- [Custom Logging in Databricks pyspark || Logging Strategies in Azure Databricks by Cloudpandith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dp1Nv4o0lrA)
- [Access Azure Blob storage using the azure DataBricks provide by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#access-azure-blob-storage-using-the-dataframe-api).

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I am currently taking. It is documented here: [How to capture cell's output in Databricks notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62774448/how-to-capture-cells-output-in-databricks-notebook)

from IPython.utils.capture import CapturedIO

capture = CapturedIO(sys.stdout, sys.stderr)

...

cmem = capture.stdout

I am writing the contents of cmem variable to a file in BLOB. BLOB is mounted to DBFS.