# Log4j Logging in Azure Databricks using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, log4j, azure-databricks

I have a azure databricks cluster onto which I have mounted a container.

Under Cluster logging section, I have provided my mounting path and I am receiving logs on my blob container but I wanted to create a logging system using log4j logger which would create a single file for a day on my blob container.

Any suggestions/documentation details would help.

Comment: Hi @Tizen. follow this reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872828/saving-pyspark-standard-out-and-standard-error-logs-to-cloud-object-storage-when/72882643#72882643)

Comment: hi @BhanunagasaiVamsi-MT given link provides logging through default python. I wanted to implement logging using log4j properties